# Can I apply dielectric grease to a blower motor resistor body?

Tags: camry, hvac, connector, corrosion, heater-blower

I have a 2001 Camry (North America model) which (in)famously puts the open-body blower resistor in the ducting to cool it, which leads to enormous corrosion and burnout problems in humid/salty climates.

My question is, when replacing the resistor, in addition to applying dielectric grease to the connectors to prevent them from rusting and burning out, **can I apply a layer to the bare body of the resistor to reduce the chances of corrosion?**

**Will this affect its ability to self-cool and conduct?**

I am also replacing the blower motor and connectors at the same time, the corrosion and resistance problem tends to cascade badly through the blower system.

Comment: Depends on what alloy the wire is. In my experience , normally resistance wires like that are Nichrome ( has a few other names) which is very resistant to oxidation in air , with or without humidity and salt. Same alloy as electric range elements. Nichrome is non-magnetic but so are many stainless steels.

Comment: @blacksmith considering the damage I’ve seen on these in other posts is usually the connector and the metal housing of the resistor taps, you’re probably right that the resistance wire would probably be fine. I’ll have to get a better look at it to see where the wire meets the housing and then just gently coat the housing.I don’t want to have to go back in there again, it was hard enough getting the first fossilized resistor out

Comment: How long did the first one last?  If it lasted 20 years, would it be an issue if the new one only lasted another 20 years?

Comment: Is this your car in the video? If so, it looks an easy enough job if you need to do it again in a few years time.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JagQlQQoYfY

Comment: @HandyHowie it took almost an hour, and a professional mechanic had to cut half of the old one out because both of the screws and the old connector had rusted solid. One of them ended up shearing off, so my new resistor is held in by just one now. Believe me, I saw the video and thought it’d be easy too

Comment: It sounds like a good idea to put that grease on the connector, but I probably wouldn’t put it on the resistor.  Hopefully you won’t need to worry about it again for quite a few years.